# Chrome extension memory leak in chrome.extension.sendMessage()?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm seeing fairly *massive* memory leaks in long-lived pages using Chrome's chrome.extension.sendMessage()

After sending ~200k events from the Content-Script to the Background-Page as a test, chrome.Event's retained size is ~80% of the retained memory in ~50MB heap snapshot

I've been trying to track down any mistakes I might be making, closing over some variable and preventing it from being GC'd, but it seems to be related to the implementation of Chrome's eventing system

Has anyone run into anything like this, or seen memory leaks with extremely long-lived extensions with Content-Scripts that chatter a lot with a bg page?

The code on my Content-Script side:

```
  csToBg = function(message) {
    var csToBgResponseHandler = function(response) {
      console.log("Got a response from bg");
      };

    var result = chrome.extension.sendMessage(null, message, csToBgResponseHandler)
  };
```

And on the Background-Page side, a simple ACK function (to superstitiously avoid https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114738):

```
var handleIncomingCSMessage = function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  var response = message;
  response.acked = "ACK";

  window.console.log("Got a message, ACKing to CS")

  sendResponse(response);
}
```

After sending ~200k messages in Chrome 23.0.1271.97 this way, the heap snapshot looks like: [image: heap snapshot]

The memory never seems to get reclaimed for the life of the page, and I'm stumped about how to fix it.

EDIT: This is a standard background page, and is **not** an event page.

Comment: The results in windows are worst than above!

Comment: First, it's worth to mention that 200K events seems not as intended use-case for single messages. Instead, [long-lived](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#connect) connections should be used. Perhaps this can lower memory consumption. Also try to change your code: `var response = {};`, plus may be `delete message;`. I've ran some tests with the changes, it looks better in snapshot, but further validation and confirmation needed.

Comment: [I've had this is issue before](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67344), it should be fixed. Weird that this is showing up again, try to report a new bug report perhaps? (or reopen my old one)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably fixed in chrome 32.

#### Finally!

see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311665 for details